# Separate buttons/TouchableOpacity elements in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am a student, working on an assessment and I am trying to resolve this problem I'm facing. Mind you, I'm quite new and I googled the issue but may have missed the solution, hence why I'm asking here - hope that is okay!

This is the code:

https://snack.expo.io/@guldenbelli/assessment-mob-dev-app

As you may notice, the 3 buttons are not separate and I cannot work around that - tried a separator, as you can see in the code, but doesn't work?

So, my question is: how can I separate the 3 buttons? (1 PC Gaming setup, 2 PC Gaming setup and 3 PC Gaming setup).

I would really appreciate the help!

Thank you,
Gulden

Comment: Do you just want to have a space between the buttons?

Comment: if yes, you just can use margin or marginVertical in the button style class

Comment: Yes, that's what I need - I see the person that answered has provided a solution as you suggested, with marginBottom :) Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a marginBottom in your TouchableOpacity Button style

```
    button: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "beige",
    marginBottom:30,
    padding: 30,
    borderRadius: 8,
    borderWidth: 0
      }
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful - just what I was looking for! Thank you again :)